# Uploading a txt file without saving it to database using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seem to be stuck on figuring out the best approach to let a user upload a text file, have my application parse the file, and then return some output via ajax directly back on the same page.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I have been using the following and it works wonderfully but I can't get it to work with ajax.

Here is the view file - index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag 'log/new', :multipart => true do %>
<label for="file">Please upload a log file to continue</label> <%= file_field_tag "file" %>
<%= submit_tag ('Upload')%>
<% end %>
```

I am then able to play with the results in my controller using `params[:file]` just fine but when I add `:remote => true` to my form it won't let me do any AJAX or run my .js.erb view file, presumably for security reasons since the js can't read the XHR request yadda yadda.

I have also tried `CarrierWave` and `jquery-fileupload-rails` gems but I don't want to save it to the database first which carrier wave seemed to want to do and jquery-fileupload seems to do the same.  In any event, even if I get the file uploaded/saved to db with one of those gems - how am I able to access the contents like I was able to with my `params[:file]` approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload file with AJAX and rails forms you can use `remotipart` gem:

> Remotipart is a Ruby on Rails gem enabling AJAX file uploads with
>   jQuery in Rails 3.0 and Rails 3.1 remote forms. This gem augments the
>   native Rails jQuery remote form functionality enabling asynchronous
>   file uploads with little to no modification to your application.

For me it works with Rails 3.2 as well.

https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

http://rubygems.org/gems/remotipart

Comment: This worked perfectly!  All I had to do was add the remotipart gem and then tag my form with `:remote => true` and it went to load the .js.erb instead of the .html.erb.  I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks again.